# chrome developer tools restore window position

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I undocked the dev-Tools of chrome so that when pressing F12, another window opens, showing the DEV-Tools.

**Problem:** For I-don't-know-what-reason the window moves to a random position whenever it's opened. currently it moved so far, that its coordinates are fully outside of my desktop. It always moves at least somewhere nearly outside my desktop.

**Question:** How to restore the window positioni if it's not reachable for grabbing?
How to avoid this happening again?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. The position should be remembered. Anyway you can use the standard OS methods: for example, in Windows 7+ you can press Win-Left or Win-Right. There are several other methods, including 3rdparty utilities.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turns out it was because I had multiple monitors and one of them had display scaling set to 125%, when I set it back to 100% the developer tools windows always appeared where I could see it entirely.

You can change the display scaling by right clicking the desktop and then clicking `Display settings`, look for the setting `Change the size of text, apps, and other items`, if it's already at 100%, click on another monitor at the top and check again.

Of course you might not like having the monitor at 100% scaling (everything will be smaller), but at least it works!